BPF custom kfunc : calling kernel function %s is not allowed
I am writing some codes for my thesis using ebpf and I need to create a custom kfunc to call within my bpf program. To do so I started by following the example here https://eunomia.dev/tutorials/43-kfuncs/#file-kfuncc as well as the one in the kernel documentation https://docs.kernel.org/6.8/bpf/kfuncs.html. The code of the lkm implementing the kfunc is the following:
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/printk.h>
#include <linux/string.h> 
#include <linux/btf.h>
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

__bpf_kfunc_start_defs();

__bpf_kfunc int bpf_strstr(char *s1, __u32 s1__sz, char *s2, __u32 s2__sz)
{
    if (s2__sz == 0) 
        return 0;

    if (s1__sz == 0 || s1__sz < s2__sz) 
        return -1;

    for (int i = 0; i <= s1__sz - s2__sz; i++)
    {
        int j = 0;
        while (j < s2__sz && s1[i + j] == s2[j])
            j++;
        if (j == s2__sz)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

__bpf_kfunc_end_defs();

/*
// kernel version > 6.8
BTF_KFUNCS_START(bpf_strstr_id_set)
BTF_ID_FLAGS(func, bpf_strstr) 
BTF_KFUNCS_END(bpf_strstr_id_set) 
*/

// kernel version <= 6.8
BTF_SET8_START(bpf_strstr_id_set)
BTF_ID_FLAGS(func, bpf_strstr, 0)
BTF_SET8_END(bpf_strstr_id_set)

static const struct btf_kfunc_id_set bpf_strstr_kfunc_set = {
        .owner = THIS_MODULE,
        .set   = &bpf_strstr_id_set,
};

static int __init myinit(void)
{
    /* Register the BTF */
    int ret = register_btf_kfunc_id_set(BPF_PROG_TYPE_TRACING, &bpf_strstr_kfunc_set);
    if(ret)
    {
        printk("Failed to load bpf_strstr kfunc : %d\n", ret);
        return ret;
    }
    printk("bpf_strstr kfunc loaded\n");
    return 0;
}

//late_initcall(myinit);

static void __exit myexit(void)
{
    printk("bpf_strstr function unloaded\n");
}

module_init(myinit)
module_exit(myexit)

While in the ebpf program I trace the file opening and I insert a simple example like the following:
// extern declaration 
extern int bpf_strstr(char *s1, __u32 s1__sz, char *s2, __u32 s2__sz) __ksym;

SEC("tracepoint/syscalls/sys_enter_open")
int tracepoint__open(struct trace_event_raw_sys_enter *ctx)
{
    // do stuff like getting cmd, file opening and pid

    const char s1[] = "Hello World";
    const char s2[] = "World";
    int ret2 = bpf_strstr(s1, sizeof(s1)-1, s2, sizeof(s2)-1);
    if(ret2 != 0)
    {
        bpf_printk("[INFO] : strstr failed : %d\n", ret2);
    }
    else
    {
        bpf_printk("[INFO] : strstr success : %d\n", ret2);
    }
    
    return 0;
}

Compilation goes fine but whenever I try to run the code the verifier fails saying that calling the kernel function %s is not allowed. It does the same even with the following example https://github.com/eunomia-bpf/bpf-developer-tutorial/tree/main/src/43-kfuncs (by cloning the entire repo and use all their libraries).
dmesg do not show any error while loading the module.
I am using ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, kernel 6.8.0-48-generic.
So even trying different sources I always get the same error.
From the verifier source code (https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.8/source/kernel/bpf/verifier.c#L11928) it seems that it is failing to fetch the kfunc meta :
// verifier source code slice of 'static int check_kfunc_call'

err = fetch_kfunc_meta(env, insn, &meta, &func_name);
if (err == -EACCES && func_name)
    verbose(env, "calling kernel function %s is not allowed\n", func_name);

more precisely it is failing to retrieve the kfunc flags:
kfunc_flags = btf_kfunc_id_set_contains(desc_btf, func_id, env->prog);
if (!kfunc_flags) {
    return -EACCES;
}

but I cannot understand why since the registration seems successful.
I don't think there is a compilation / library problem since I tried the eunomia example linked above where they provide their own libraries and Makefile.
Maybe some kernel configuration options?
EDIT : problem solved
Basically using the tracepoint SEC("tracepoint/syscalls/*") results in a BPF_PROG_TYPE_TRACEPOINT, while to call a kfunc the supported PROG_TYPE are listed in this function : https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.11.8/source/kernel/bpf/btf.c#L8306 . As we can see, there is no BPF_PROG_TYPE_TRACEPOINT (only a 'TRACING' one). Problem has been solved by switching to kprobes. I still don't know if somehow is possible to have a "tracepoint/syscall/*" resulting in a BPF_PROG_TYPE_TRACING.
